# How to verify Apple ID if iPhone at the same time blocks gmail access?

Tags: iphone, apple-id

I have set up iCloud and Apple ID, but keeps telling me to verify my Apple ID. It won't let me download the Gmail app to access my emails to verify my Apple ID.

How do I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does iTunes ask me to verify an email account that's already verified?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3627/why-does-itunes-ask-me-to-verify-an-email-account-thats-already-verified)

Comment: I'm actually upvoting this. It's not the clearest statement, but it serves as a foil for a nice answer by Wingless Winter and we're really about good answers here...

Answer (score 2):

So you need to verify your new created Apple ID using Gmail?

Why don't you browse to http://gmail.com and manually log-in via the web interface?

Comment: Yes - separating the issues is the clear solution here. Fixing an Apple ID from a computer (even if you have to go to a library to borrow one) is often faster than messing about on a new iOS device when your account is locked or you don't have your security questions/password in order.

Comment: user117156 could even log into Gmail in the iOS Safari, too, instead of searching out a computer or another device.

Comment: @IconDaemon Yes - I find most people that can navigate Safari for web apps, don't generally ask for help with Apple ID - but it's well worth mentioning that it's possible :-) Especially if no other computer is handy.